# How do I stop my dropdown menu pushing down the page?

Tags: menu

How do I stop my dropdown menu pushing down the page?

When I hover over the services button it pushes down the page contents.

http://jsfiddle.net/tPh9P/

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
ul#main-nav li ul {
    padding:0;
    display:none;
}
```

to this:

```
ul#main-nav li ul {
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    display:none;
}
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/tPh9P/2/)

(By the way, in future, it's best to post HTML/CSS/general coding questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), and include the sample code in your question if you can.)

Comment: wow that was quick, thanks heaps. Thanks for your help and tip.